# Selecting an overall directory in HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html, css

In the root directory of an example website I have the following:

- [FOLDER]about-us
- [FOLDER]style
- index.php
- site.php

Within the "about-us" folder, I have other PHP pages. Within the "style" folder, I have another folder labelled "includes" which, inside that, has another page labelled "footer.php".

My problem is, I want to link the "site.php" file within the footer. However, using this code won't work throughout multiple directories:

```html
<a href="../../site.php">Site</a>
```

How can I still use the same "footer.php" insert within each page, no matter which directory it may be in?

Comment: you can use `href="/site.php"` - this will point to root folder always

Comment: @Lashane +1 ahhhhh....you beat me to it...i was just about to suggest that

Comment: Ah, i didn't honestly think to try that! Appreciated